# Highcharts Pie/Donut Chart highlighting and aligning labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts, label

I have an pie chart with data labels, that are directly at the point and show the value and name of it. But I got some issues I couldn't solve, even after hours of trying and googling.

- I want to let one label stand out, by increasing the font size. I managed it through using the formatter and adding an inline-style, but I don't know if there is an easier/better solution.
- In some cases the labels might be overflowing, so the get cropped. Thats alright, but if the text has multiple words, I would like to do a break before cropping the text.
- All labels that are on the left side of the pie should be text-aligned `right` and on the right side text-aligned `left`. So that they are always aligning towards the center. I haven't even figured out a way to change the text-alignment at all.

I created a small JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x503prs6/54/

Thanks for reading and all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Inside events [chart.events.load](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) you can also update style for specific data labels.

```
   events: {
      load: function() {
        let chart = this;
        chart.series[0].data[0].update({
          dataLabels: {
            useHTML: true,
            style: {
              fontSize: '20px',
              color: 'red',
            }
          }
        })
      }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vnbxf64a/

Other options is change properties format and add breaks, to customize the text truncation in data tables you have the option to add extra CSS styles in line.

```
  dataLabels: {
    useHTML: true,
    format: '<p class="truncate"><b>{point.name}</b></br>{point.y}</p>',
    style: {
      fontSize: '20px',
      color: 'red',
      textOverflow: 'ellipsis'
    }
  }

.truncate {
    width: 220px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vnbxf64a/1/

Try use `alignTo: 'plotEdges'`, they set label touches the nearest vertical edge of the plot area, but I'm not sure how exactly you want to align the labels.
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.alignTo

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebastian Hajdus. That helped me a lot!